# Is there SASL implementation that works on Android?

Tags: android, sasl

Android has no SASL by default. Curious, if there some 3rd party implementation that can be used on Android? Did some one try http://www.cryptix.org/?

Answer (score 2):

We're using [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) in our project. It replaces default [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) implementation by [its own](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/source/browse/#hg/src/custom/de/measite/smack). It's been working so far without any issues. it uses Apache Harmony SASL client.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this one?
[android-sasl](http://github.com/koterpillar/android-sasl)

Comment: That source tree specifies GPL, not LGPL.  I assume it's a good choice for free projects, but if you're working on something non-free, keep looking.