# Sasl with android

Tags: android, sasl

Why 
import javax.security.sasl.Sasl; does not work with android ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there SASL implementation that works on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327615/is-there-sasl-implementation-that-works-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a portion of the sun jdk that the Google Android SDK team decided to provide.  The supporting classes are probably a) a lower priority or b) sun proprietary.