# ClassDefNotFound Error in Android when AWS connection is made

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been working on a android project to connect to the tables stored at my EC2 instances. I have made the connection code separately and tested it. It is showing the output as desired but the issue is that when i try to integrate the code to an Android Project it throws the error "ClassDefNotFound" Error of some Hive libraries.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.blockbuster;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button searchButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    }

    public void clickSearch(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PopulateOnUi.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

PopulateOnUi.java

```
package com.example.blockbuster;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class PopulateOnUi extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listview;
    TextView tv1;
    String data = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_populate_on_ui);
        String[] values = new String[]{"data1","data2","data3","data4", "data5"};
        String data = null;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String driverName = "com.amazon.hive.jdbc3.HS2Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //      System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:10000/default", "", "");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String tableName = "msd";
            // show tables
            String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
            //System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if (res.next()) {
                //  System.out.println(res.getString(1));
                data = res.getString(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setText(data);
        //listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        //  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        //              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,data);
        //      listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I have added all the jars that were required by the connectionHive part in the build path of the android project and also the permissions "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"" [Logs file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8w1SGcSVMVdR3d3UFV6Vk54WFU). Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: You need to post the actual exception from your application logs. It will tell you exactly what class it can't find.

Comment: Added the Log files.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message it specifically says it can't find the class `javax.security.sasl.Sasl`. This class isn't packaged with Android and you will need to include it in your application. [This](https://github.com/koterpillar/android-sasl) looks like a likely place to start.

You might also try reading the other similar questions that have been asked here, like this one: [Is there SASL implementation that works on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327615/is-there-sasl-implementation-that-works-on-android)

Comment: can you elaobrate which .jar file to be added to build path. to get things working? Do i only have to add the jar in build path or some piece of code will be put into it?

Comment: I added javax-sasl.jar to my build path and things didnt worked for me